# Grant domain users Admin privileges for certain application?

Tags: administrator

I don't want domain users to install new software so I have to take away the admin privileges. But certain applications require admin privileges for users. How can I sort this?

Can I create a new local group and grant certain admin privileges?

Comment: What is it that they require admin privileges for?

Comment: Governmental software for finance etc.

Comment: As in I mean what is the software trying to do that requires admin permissions?

Comment: protected data since its governmental

Comment: How is it protected? Is it on the machine or accessed over a network?
Either way the application needing admin credentials for this doesn't make sense. Either their user is permissioned to read (and/or write) that data or it isn't.

Comment: If a user needs to grant administrator rights to an application in order to access it or whatever data it contains then you are doing it wrong. Correct permissions or app restrictions should be used instead of making things worse by accidentally giving someone admin access and potentially exposing the entire system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ultimately depends on how secure you want your environment. For maximum security, a user should never have administrative access. Thus, the best way to do this is to have an admin run the app by elevating as local admin (NOT using domain admin credentials to prevent password dumping), and then creating a service or something that starts up as admin and then runs the application. That way, you have fine grain control, and you can allow the application to be run as admin, without giving the user admin rights, and exposing yourself to all kinds of attacks that require admin privileges, such as ARP poisoning MITM, NBT-NS spoofing and NTLMv2 MITM, password dumping, etc.

Schtasks should be able to accomplish this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have found that I could create shortcut by using runas /ComputerName/Admin /savecred. But saving credentials isn't really good idea to me. I have done some research and was unable to find where the cred is saved, and whether it is encrypted or not.  Other solutions I found, I tried disabling msiexec.exe in regedit and gpedit; I tried several install blocking in gpedit. nothing worked. If possible could you please give more details on running the app with elevated privilege.

Comment: You are correct. It is never a good idea to include passwords in scripts. You can create a scheduled task to run the program as SYSTEM using a local admin account.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally feasible to create local groups and then granting them access specifics rights (folders, registry keys, ...) but that will always depend on the application requirements, and scalability can be a problem. So I you have any example on those applications, feel free to share it.

Meanwhile, I can suggest the following solutions to address your problem:

- **[Separated admin account]** : give each user a separated account that will be part of the local administrators group of their machine
- **[Power users group]**: try to add concerned users account into this group which has some limited administrative powers and then try if the application can run
- **[Run as tool]**: may be the best solution to your problem ([source](http://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-0/)). It allows to run some specific applications with administrator privileges that you have defined without needing the user to be administrator (see image below)

[image: Run as software]

Hope that will help.